# Rails: update multiple records single column value while the records were retrieved using a group by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am retrieving some data from a table using a group by clause and after that I want to update a single column value for all the records which were retrieved by the initial query.

So I need to make sure that since the initial query until I update the records no new line were added.

Explanation: So lets say the model `Test` has 5 columns: `Id A B C Status`

So first I query as follows:

```
Test.select('count(*), A, B').where(status:'new', C: 'value').group('A, B')
```

After I process the groups in code I want to change the status of all the records that were `used` by the initial query to `done`

Problem is that if I just do:

```
Test.where(status: 'new', C: 'value')
```

In order to now use `update_all` there is chance new records were added to the table since the first query that answer this condition and I will set their status to 'Done' although they weren't really processed because during the initial query they didn't exist.

So basically I need a way to either lock the table from insertions since the initial query until the update OR in some way get a list of the id's that were "considered" in the group by query.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to select id too from the select statement in first query.

```
Test.select('count(*), A, B, Id').where(status:'new', C: 'value').group('A, B').
```

select the ids from the above query.Then use another query to update them.

```
Test.where("Id IN ?", ids ).update_all()
```

update with the necessary changes your require.

Comment: No need to iterate over each `Test` object, you can do a `update_all` over the `ActiveRecord::Relation` returned by `Test.where()`

Comment: Thanks my friend. Updated the answer.

Comment: I dont get it. Doesnt adding 'id' to the group_by ruin the whole point of group_by? Am I missing something?

Comment: The id is unique if that wasnt clear for some reason

Comment: Are you able to group without using Id? then you can remove Id from group. Since you select Id, it may sometimes ask you to add Id to your group.

Comment: Ill need to check that. Pretty sure thats not possible. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### group_by and having with update_all (Rails 7+)

[Starting from Rails 7, you can use group_by and having with update_all](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43465).

So now, it is possible to write a query like this:

```rb
Post.joins(:comments).group("posts.id").having("count(comments.id) >= 2").update_all
```

That generates the following SQL ([query may differ depending on DBMS](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43465)):

```sql
UPDATE "posts" SET "flagged" = ? WHERE "posts"."id" IN (
  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
  GROUP BY posts.id HAVING (count(comments.id) >= 2)
)  [["flagged", "t"]]
```

It selects and updates records in a single transaction.

**Sources**:

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43465).
- [Rails 7 adds the ability to delete and update queries using GROUP_BY and HAVING](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/12/15/rails-7-updates-to-group-by-and-having) by [Saeloun](https://blog.saeloun.com/).